# HTML5 Client-side App Open File Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, vue.js, client-side

Ok, so first, let me explain that I've researched this extensively and am completely aware of the security implications. This is a client-side app using JavaScript, Vue, and pure HTML5.

I use a hidden input type file to get the file dialog.

```
<input id="image-input" class="hidden" type="file" accept="image/*" @change="imageFileSelected">
<button type="button" title="Change Image" @click="openImage"><img src="icons/open-image.png"></button>
```

You can ignore the fact that I'm using Vue because these are just the native onclick and onchange events. The problem applies to HTML5 in general. The button triggers the hidden file input just fine in Firefox, Edge, and Chrome. However, I noticed a problem with the later two, which is that the onchange event is not fired when you select the same file twice.

I've already seen the millions of other topics suggesting value = null. That solution works perfectly fine, except for one small trivial detail. Firefox will remember the last file that you uploaded and automatically select it, hence adding this fix for Chrome and Edge, breaks that desirable functionality that's present in Firefox. The reason I want the dialog to remember the last file is because of the nature of app itself. I expect that users may want to work on one of the files and then decide to start over by reloading the same file again.

```
openImage() {
    var el = document.getElementById('image-input');
    el.value = null;
    el.click();
},
```

Other apps that exhibit this same issue:

1. http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
2. https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/dist/index.html
3. https://fineuploader.com/demos.html

It seems nobody else is aware of this or else just doesn't care about whether their dialogs remember the last selected file. Regardless, does anyone know a way to fix this problem without breaking the Firefox functionality I find desirable?

Comment: why not check if its firefox then not apply the fix?

Comment: That's one possibility, but I do not like it because I can never be sure if Firefox is going to change its behavior. For example, will Firefox always allow selecting the same file twice in future versions? Ideally, I'd want the dialog on Edge and Chrome to also remember the file like Firefox does.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (I was only testing Firefox and Chrome). I wanted chrome to fire the 'change' event even if the same file was selected again.

I did the **reset to empty string** as shown below below after handling the click event, so for you the code would be like this :

```js
openImage() {
  var el = document.getElementById('image-input');
  el.click();
  el.value = ""; // instead of el.value = null
}.
```

I dint test Edge browser. Maybe you can try this and tell if it works on Edge also. Hope it helps :)